# Laravel incorrect email issue in Login

Tags: php, laravel

I have login registration module which is built using auth.Every think is working fine.Suppose  i have following email id `vision+myvison@gmail.com` in database user table but when i try to login its giving incorrect email.I am pretty sure that its giving error because of `plus` in email id.In my project its necessary to accept plus because of alias.Can any one help me how to fix this issue.I am using raw query

```
$userDetails = DB::table('users')->select('id', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'password', 'role', 'confirm', 'status')->where('email', $email)->first();
```

**Updated**

```
public function login(Request $request) {    
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'password' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) { 
            echo "error";
        }
        $email = $request->input('email');
        $password = $request->input('password'); 
        \Log::info($email);

        $userDetails = DB::table('users')->select('id', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'password', 'role', 'confirm', 'status')->where('email', $email)->first();

        if (count($userDetails) != 0) {
```

**Updated 2**

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/auth/login') }}">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
                        <h4 class="nomargin">Sign in</h4>

                        <input type="text" class="form-control uname" name="email" placeholder="email" autocomplete="off" value="{{ old('email') }}" />
                        <input type="password" class="form-control pword" name="password" placeholder="password" autocomplete="off" />
                        <a style="color:#17a08c" href="{{ url('/password/email') }}"><small>Forgot Password</small></a>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block text-capitalise">Sign in</button>
                    </form>
```

Comment: Before the line you've written above, can you do a `\Log::info($email)` and see what's being passed into the query builder? The logged message will be available in `storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: @LionelChan.Thanks for the suggestion .i am getting white space instead of plus

Comment: @LionelChan.is there a way to accept plus in email

Comment: How have you submitted the post? Can you show us the snippet where you post the login form?

Comment: @LionelChan.updated question

Comment: Can you paste your view code snippet in question I mean login form ? Also how are you submitting the form, via `get` or `post` ? If it's `get` then `plus(+)` is an issue in URL parameter.

Comment: @MahfuzulAlam.its post

Comment: @MahfuzulAlam.Yes you are right .i am using api in that i am passing it to get method

Comment: So you need to encode parameters before passing, so that it won't remove `+`.

Comment: @MahfuzulAlam.Thanks a lot .you have saved my precious hours

Comment: Please mark this as helpful if it really helps.

Comment: @MahfuzulAlam.Can you add your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're submitting via `get` method then plus(+) is an issue in URL and replaced by white space. You need to encode parameters before passing, so that it won't remove +.

Answer (score -1):

put a double quotation in your $eamil variable like the following it mat work:

```
$userDetails = DB::table('users')->select('id', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'password', 'role', 'confirm', 'status')->where('email',"$email")->first();
```

Comment: .its not query issue .issue with email.$request->input('email') trim plus in email

Comment: that means laravel is validating the email removing plus sign and the value rendered from $request->input('email') is vision myvison@gmail.com and not vision+myvison@gmail.com ?